# Why is Nouruz celebrated all over the Turkic states of the former Soviet Union, but not in Turkey?

Tags: turkey, central-asia, festival

[Nouruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowruz) is an old Iranian festival, basically the Iranian or Persian New Year. However, it is not only celebrated by speakers of Persian and closely related languages (i.e. not only among Iranians, Afghans, Tajiks or Kurds), but also among many Turkic-speaking peoples. E.g. it is a public holiday in Azerbaijan, Kazakhstan, Uzbekistan, Turkmenistan and Kirgizistan. Nouruz is also a public holiday in Albania, which is not Turkic-speaking, but which happens to have been a part of the Ottoman empire.

Given that Nouruz celebrations are so widespread among Turkic-speaking peoples, why do Turks in Turkey not celebrate it?

I am assuming there is some history-related reason, that is why I am posting the question here. I have read the wp article linked to above. I am aware that Kurds in Turkey *do* celebrate Nouruz and that the festival used to be a focal point of Kurdish nationalism in Turkey in the 1990s. But I believe that is a consequence of Turks not celebrating, rather than a cause for it.

Comment: It's usually pretty difficult to say definitively why something *didn't* or doesn't happen (why don't they celebrate Nowruz in France?  The exception might be if there was a strong reason to think that something should have happened, but then it didn't.  In this case, I don't see any strong reason to expect Turks and Turkic people in other places to have developed similar customs.  On the other hand, it might be interesting to ask why Nowruz is celebrate those other places.  The short version is there are/were Iranian people living there and they were in the Persian sphere of influence.

Comment: @Juhasz Thanks a lot. You are raising a very interesting point, though Iranian influence does not yet really explain why Nevruz is celebrated in Albania.

Comment: Yeah, Albania is a weird one.  That could also make a good question.  There I'm totally out of my element, but I wouldn't be surprised if the answer had something to do with Bektashis being Shia and/or the group's founder being possibly Persian.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, this is one of those "why did something not happen" questions that's easy to answer: Nowruz is a [very politically charged holiday in Turkey](https://www.aljazeera.com/features/2023/3/21/a-sad-subdued-nowruz-for-syrias-kurds) and was banned there from 1925 to 1992. The Kurds were able to keep it a part of their culture in communities that were [part of other states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdish_immigration_into_Syria).

Had many Turks in Turkey celebrated it before 1925? It seems unlikely. Nowruz was originally a Zoroastrian holiday, as Wikipedia mentions. Its celebration greatly predates [Turkic migration into Anatolia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine%E2%80%93Seljuk_wars). The nomadic Turkic peoples who moved into Zoroastrian-influenced areas such as Central Asia adopted the custom, and the ones who moved past it and into Anatolia did not.

> [до проникновения ислама в регион идеологическое содержание Навруза было связано с местными вариантами зороастризма](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342277117_Prazdnovanie_Navruza_v_Buhare_i_Samarkande_v_ritualnoj_praktike_i_obsestvennyh_diskursah_vtoraa_polovina_XIX_-_nacalo_XX_veka).

> until Islam reached the region [central asia], the ideological content of Nowruz was tied to the local variants of Zoroastrianism

Comment: Interesting, but what about Albania then ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the Seljuks moved "past" Central Asia? Also judging by the presence of Persian words in modern Turkish, Persian cultural influence seems to have been reasonably strong for Turkish Turks as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting points have already been raised, however one important point is missing:

Nouruz is traditionally associated with important dates in the life of [Imam Ali](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali): either his birth (might be the more "popular" explanation?) or with a [declaration of Muhammad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghadir_Khumm) supposed to mean that he wanted Ali to be his successor (this is maybe the more official explanation?).

Note that there is a [separate holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Ghadir) for that latter event in the Islamic lunar calender. And also note that "associated" here does not necessarily mean that those other event *really* happened around March 21st.

This association with Imam Ali would explain why Shiite Albanians and Alevite Turks celebrate this holiday, but Sunni Turks not so much.

See also [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11960/why-do-shia-celebrate-nowruz) on another stack.

---

There is, however, another aspect to explain why Nouruz is not much celebrated in Turkey:

Nouruz was actually a noted date in Ottoman times. There was a [whole genre of poems](https://tr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevr%C3%BBziyye) written for the occasion ([example](https://tr.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Nevruziye), by [Nedim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ned%C3%AEm)), and cooks in the Topkapı palace presented special foods to the court members on the occasion.

After the end of the Ottoman empire, it seems the tradition initially continued, and festivities were held in Ankara [until 1925](https://ataturkansiklopedisi.gov.tr/bilgi/milli-mucadele-ve-ataturk-devrinde-nevruz-kutlamalari/), but the old date of Nouruz had now become connected to the [Ernegekon legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergenekon) about the origin of the Türks. Still not sure why Nouruz did not continue to be celebrated afterwards, however.